# Switch primary and secondary screen with keyboard shortcut

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, keyboard-shortcuts, external-display

I have two screen one is monitor which is secondary screen and is in extended mode and another is laptop which is primary screen.
Whenever I open anything new it opens in primary screen(i.e. laptop) and then I have to drag it to secondary screen(i.e. monitor).

Is there any shortcut to switch primary screen and secondary screen which let me open file in screen where I have opened it?

Comment: After opening anything, you can use Win+SHIFT+Left (/right) arrow to move it to your other screen.

Comment: @MátéJuhász, that will take active window tab from one monitor to another, my question is how to make primary monitor as secondary and secondary as primary ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your keyboard allows you to customise the fn keys behavior, here is how to do it:

- Download [NirSoft](http://launcher.nirsoft.net/downloads/index.html) (it has a bunch of useful tools)
- Extract the file `multimonitortool.exe` (under NirSoft folder) to the desired location.
- Create a txt file next to it (the name doesn't matter), and put that content inside:

```
.\multimonitortool.exe /SetNextPrimary
```

- Save and rename the extension to `.bat`

If you run this file, it will switch your primary monitor to the next available.

Now you can setup your keyboard to execute that file when a specific Fn key is pressed.

Comment: worked for me. Thanks. Just to add further detail, the .bat file can be named anything you want

Comment: Indeed, I have updated the answer to avoid potential confusion

Comment: also,  wanted to mention, I am executing these. BAT files with EventGhost via JOIN API calls triggered by IFTTT. For e.g., I have Google Assistant routines, i.e., "desk mode", "couch mode", which are the say phrase conditions in IFTTT applets. Very cool stuff! Couch mode uses NirSorft to set my TV to primary, moves all windows to primary, sets the audio source to couch speakers/ soundbar, and dims the desk monitor. Desk mode uses NirSoft to set my desk monitor to primary, moves all windows to primary, sets the audio source to desk speakers, and resets the desk monitor brightness.